# What SQL operation should I use?

Tags: sql, database-design, join

I have two tables:

```
TABLE 'songs'
song_id   --some other columns about this song
-------
1
2
3

TABLE 'song_ownership'
user_id      song_id
-------      -------
28           1
28           3
538          1
234          2
```

I'm interested in performing a query where given a `user_id` I'm returned all of the songs that they own. You can see that user 28 owns two songs, for example.

Incidentally, this is the best I know how to normalize this table and am open to suggestions on how to store this data more conventionally (I'm just learning SQL). Is this a typical table setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select songs.*
from songs
inner join song_ownership on song_ownership.song_id = songs.song_id and     
song_ownership.user_id=@user_id
```

Assuming that the same user can't own the same song twice.  Your normalization looks fine so far!  Your song_ownership table will be a "many-to-many" table, and (if a song-user association is unique), you can put a compound primary key on both columns, and your users will be in a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * -- choose only the columns you're interested to, like user id and song name
from songs
     inner join song_ownership on song_ownership.song_id=songs.song_id
where song_ownership.user_id=?
```